# Switch is being undelined in red and i don't know the reason

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to java trying to learn it, so far so good until now getting an error which i can't seem to find the reason. I am using netbeans IDE
The error is that the switch statement is being underlined in red and on the case level it is telling orphaned case.

I tried to `import java.lang.String`

```
package chatprogram;

import java.util.*;

public class ChatProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = keyboard.nextLine();

        Switch(s){
            case "Hi":
                System.out.println("Hi");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `switch` not `Switch`

Comment: oops ! now it says string in switch not supported in -source 1.6 ! what does this mean ?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: how can i know and what does source 1.6 mean ?

Comment: It seems you are using JDK 1.6 which not support switch (I think) I suggest to upgrade your jdk to 8+

Comment: i have 6 and i have 12 ! and i am using netbeans 7.0 so how can i make netbeans use 12 ?

Comment: Netbeans 7.0 not support JDK 12, so download the last version of Netbeans or use another IDE

Comment: i needed a pre apache version, so i'll download 8.2

Comment: I believe NetBeans 8.2 only supports Java up to version 8. Is there a reason you can't use an Apache NetBeans version (or Eclipse or IntelliJ)?

Comment: i do have eclipse and intellij but the thing is i am following a book to learn java it is called Learning Java through games and it uses Netbeans so i just want to be on the same side

Answer (score 0):

first problem was "switch" instead of "Switch"
second i am using Netbeans 7.0 which has jdk 1.6 which doesn't support switch(String) so i should use a newer jdk so i switched from netbeans to eclipse